# (AndroidTouchGallery) How to start with 2,3,4.. image. How to set position

Tags: android, position, android-viewpager, android-gallery

I`m trying to implement ImageGallery on Android. I use [AndroidTouchGallery](http://github.com/Dreddik/AndroidTouchGallery) library. In MainActyvity I have list of images and by clicking on them open AndroidTouchGallery. Everything work, but when open the image gallery starts with the first one.

There need to set the image position, in which to start. In this stage I have a problem. Maybe someone how to make it.

```
int pos ; //Picture Position 

UrlPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new UrlPagerAdapter(Full_Image_Activity.this, ArrayImgBig);
mViewPager = (GalleryViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewer);
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
mViewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
```

The code of UrlPageAdapter. I try to set the position in setPrimaryItem, but it still open the first image.

```
/**
 Class wraps URLs to adapter, then it instantiates {@link UrlTouchImageView} objects to paging up through them.
 */
public class UrlPagerAdapter extends BasePagerAdapter {

    public UrlPagerAdapter(Context context, List<String> resources)
    {
        super(context, resources);
    }
    @Override
    public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);
        ((GalleryViewPager)container).mCurrentView = ((UrlTouchImageView)object).getImageView();
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position){
        final UrlTouchImageView iv = new UrlTouchImageView(mContext);
        iv.setUrl(mResources.get(position));
        iv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        collection.addView(iv, 0);
        return iv;
    }
}
```

BasePagerAdapter

```
/**
 Class wraps URLs to adapter, then it instantiates <b>UrlTouchImageView</b> objects to paging up through them.
 */
public class BasePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    protected final List<String> mResources;
    protected final Context mContext;
    protected int mCurrentPosition = -1;
    protected OnItemChangeListener mOnItemChangeListener;
    public BasePagerAdapter()
    {
        mResources = null;
        mContext = null;
    }
    public BasePagerAdapter(Context context, List<String> resources)
    {
        this.mResources = resources;
        this.mContext = context;
    }
    @Override
    public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);
        if (mCurrentPosition == position) return;
        GalleryViewPager galleryContainer = ((GalleryViewPager)container);
        if (galleryContainer.mCurrentView != null) galleryContainer.mCurrentView.resetScale();

        mCurrentPosition = position;
        if (mOnItemChangeListener != null) mOnItemChangeListener.onItemChange(mCurrentPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view){
        collection.removeView((View) view);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return mResources.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object){
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(ViewGroup arg0){
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1){
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState(){
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void startUpdate(ViewGroup arg0) { }

    public int getCurrentPosition() { return mCurrentPosition; }

    public void setOnItemChangeListener(OnItemChangeListener listener) { mOnItemChangeListener = listener; }

    public static interface OnItemChangeListener 
    {
        public void onItemChange(int currentPosition);
    }
}
```

Olso I have some other queston.

*is the "setPrimaryItem" set up the main Item(Image) witch is open first?

*is the "instantiateItem" initialise every item from the array, whitch is shows?

Answer (score 1):

I made it by this:

```
            mViewPager = (GalleryViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewer);
            mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);


            //set position
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);
```